# I need to limit CSS style cascading

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="canvas red">
    <div>
        <div class="canvas blue">
           <div>
               has blue border
               <div class="canvas red">
                   ...
                   <div>
                   MUST HAVE RED BORDER
                   </div>
               </div>           
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the css code:

```
div.canvas div {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

div.canvas.red div {
    border-width: 4px;
    border-color: red;
}

div.canvas.blue div {

    border-color: blue;
}
```

The problems are 3:

- The innermost `div.canvas.red div` receives `blue` border because it is inside `div.canvas.blue` in the hierarchy. I need to stop this css inheritance so that the innermost `div.canvas.red div` will not get twisted by `div.canvas.blue`.
- I cannot control the nesting of the divs above, because of dynamically inserting components in the web page. There can be various nesting scenarios that I must handle.
- I must not change the css structure and the way it is applied - like `canvas` and `red`/`blue` etc being separate class names, instead of having `canvas_red` and `canvas_blue` as different classes.

---

I do not plan to support IE6, therefore I can use the `>` token in my css. However, I was unable to properly take advantage of it. I'd apreciate if you change my code using it more appropriately.

Comment: You can't stop CSS inheritance. But you can override it. Using !important is one way.

Comment: @Jawad: That's nonsense. Overriding and inheritance are two totally different things.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: The problem has nothing to do with nested elements, but I see that the code has changed so I deleted my answer.

Comment: @BoltClock: Right than. Let's upvote your answer. Different things to maniplate the same "things"?

Comment: Yes, I am very sorry, but I was in a hurry and gave wrong html and css, forgive me for that. I now have updated it to reflect my issue

Comment: @BoltClock - The OP wants to style a `div` within a `div.red` without obliterating `div.blue` styles that fall within `div.red` elements. The first approach would be `div.red div`, but that causes problems. If you can characterize it more accurately, be my guest. `:)`

Comment: Which elements do you want to have 4px borders? Only red ones or both red and blue? Note also that if you don't specify a border color they'll all default to the same color as the text.

Comment: @BoltClock, the 4px border example was flawed, I fixed my post. The actual issue is that I did not expect the innermost `div.canvas.red div` to have blue border.

Comment: Updated fiddle (didn't catch the CSS update): http://jsfiddle.net/4LgaA/3/ (@BoltClock)

Comment: Don't know if this "helps", but does this do what you suggest? http://jsfiddle.net/4LgaA/5/

Comment: That's the cascade, not inheritance.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, almost there, I think that the blue borders are too big and some of the blue divs should not have borders. The answer I accepted handles the situation up to my requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not plan to support IE6, therefore I can use the `>` token in my css. However, I was unable to properly take advantage of it. I'd apreciate if you change my code using it more appropriately.

This should be what you're looking for:

```
div.canvas > div {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

div.canvas.red > div {
    border-width: 4px;
    border-color: red;
}

div.canvas.blue > div {
    border-color: blue;
}
```

Keep in mind that border styles are *not* inherited by child elements from their parents by default. The behavior you're seeing with descendant selectors is a simple effect of cascading (due to the equal specificity of your selectors), as well as the nature of the descendant selector itself to look at any level of nesting.

The child selector `>` doesn't increase specificity, but it does limit the nesting depth to only one level (i.e. `div.canvas.blue > div` cannot match the innermost element in `<div class="canvas blue"><div><div>`), which is why the resulting styles will be different.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.canvas,
div.canvas div {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

div.canvas.red {
    border-width: 4px;
    border-color: red;
}

div.canvas.blue {
    border-color: blue;
}
```